# Regex - get code between two comments

Tags: java, regex

How can I get

```
Text t;
Graph g;
```

from

```
// Co
Text t;
Graph g;
// Co
```

?

```
// Co\r?\n(.*)\r?\n// Co
```

works when there is one line, but does not work with multiple lines.

Comment: Are you sure it's safe to use this? What if you have the second // Co inside a string?

Comment: Between // Co and // Co always will be var declaration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `.` matches any character except newlines (`\n`), but you can use [the `Pattern.DOTALL` flag](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) to make it match newlines as well. So, for example, instead of this:

```
final Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("// Co\r?\n(.*)\r?\n// Co");
```

you would use this:

```
final Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("// Co\r?\n(.*)\r?\n// Co", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Equivalently, you can set the `s` flag inside the regex itself, using either of these styles:

```
final Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("// Co\r?\n((?s).*)\r?\n// Co");
final Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("// Co\r?\n(?s:(.*))\r?\n// Co");
```

which lets you control exactly which part of the regex accepts a newline for `.`. (But I'd stick with the `DOTALL` approach unless you have a regex where `.` sometimes means the one thing, sometimes the other.)

**Edited to add:** It seems very likely — but you'll have to determine this for yourself, based on your use-case — that you need to use *non-greedy* quantification, `.*?`, rather than *greedy* quantification, `.*`.

Comment: That's because `Matcher.matches()` only returns `true` if the pattern matches the *entire* string. Your test-string ends with `// Co\n`; nothing in the pattern matches that newline. I assume that what you really want is `Matcher.find()`, which returns `true` if the pattern matches any *part* of the string.